# How to add a region block to the custom template contact form page?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I trying to add a region block to custom template Contact Form page: "contact-message-feedback-form.html.twig"

Define a region (like: contact_info) to theme-name.info.yml and
add {{ page.contact_info }} in contact-message-feedback-form.html.twig

Contact form rendered successful but when add block to the region not display block in this region.

theme-name.theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function crown_ui_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'contact_message_feedback_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
    ]
  ];
}
```

theme-name.info.yml:

```
regions:
  contact_info: 'Contact Info'
```

contact-message-feedback-form.html.twig:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
{{ page.contact_info }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to load and render a block on any where in Drupal.
Read more on the module docs:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak